# Fit polygon in SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon

I have a problem with an svg element: I can't fit the polygon in the SVG element.
I have a series of hexagons made with polygons elements inside SVG elements, but if you play the snippet below you'll notice that the polygon has a white space before itself in the upper part of the SVG.

The HTML code has no space, and I tried to set `font-size: 0;` or `vertical-align` to the polygon but nothing changes.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance

```html
<html><head>
  <title>Hexagons</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="hexagons"><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg></div>
  
 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Set display: flex; to #hexagons and flex-wrap: wrap; And then you can adjust position of .hex elements by using margin

Comment: Using `viewBox="0 2 30 26"`as in @TemaniAfif's answer is doing the trick. Also you repeat yourself a lot. You may want to reuse the polygon with an `<use> element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `vertical-align` you need to adjust the height and viewbox of the SVG `height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26"`. The path height is only `26` and it start at `2` from the top

```css
#hexagons {
  width:200px;
}
svg {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagons">
<svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg><svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg>
</div>
```

I suspect you want to have a pattern so you can consider background:

```css
#hexagons {
  width:calc(20*30px);
  height:calc(10*26px);
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg>')
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagons"></div>
```

Also like this:

```css
#hexagons {
  width: calc(20*30px);
  height: calc(10*26px);
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="60" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg>'),
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class="hex" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="60" height="26" viewBox="0 2 30 26" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="30,15 23,28 8,28 0,15 8,2 23,2"></polygon></svg>') 30px 13px
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagons"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I was searching for! I only added the `viewBox` attribute and it worked out fine. But how did you understood the distance of 2 pixels from the top?

Comment: @MarDenDev if you read the polygon you will see the two points on the top `8,2 23,2`. you will notice the `2`